# Cassandra partitioning of composite keys

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

From what i understand, if we have a single primary key, this key is used in order to partition the data and store it in a node (using random partitioner for instance).

Now what I'm not sure about is that if i have multiple `keys` (aka composite keys), is the combination of the keys used to partition the data or is it going to be the first primary key?

As an example, for a single key column family such as:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    userid uuid,
    emailaddress text,
    birthday timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (userid)
);
```

I know the `userid` is used in order to determine to which node(s) a row of type `users` should be partitioned.

If I change this table to

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    userid uuid,
    emailaddress text,
    birthday timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (userid, emailaddress)
);
```

Does this mean that now `userid` and `emailaddress` are going to be used together in order to determine the partitions?

Would it be possible for two rows, having the same `userid` but different `emailaddress` to be allocated in two separate nodes or would they always be in the same node?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact in your example

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    userid uuid,
    emailaddress text,
    birthday timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (userid, emailaddress)
);
```

userid is partition key part and emailaddress is clustering column and in cqlsh

```
cqlsh:rw> CREATE TABLE users ( userid INT, email TEXT, data TEXT, PRIMARY KEY ( userid, email ) );
cqlsh:rw> SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = 0;

 userid | email | data
```

Partition key part is defined by inner braces ()

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    userid uuid,
    emailaddress text,
    birthday timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY ((userid, emailaddress))
);
```

now you will have partition key consisting of userid and emailaddress and in cqlsh again

```
cqlsh:rw> CREATE TABLE users ( userid INT, email TEXT, data TEXT, PRIMARY KEY ( ( userid, email ) ) );                                                                                                                                                                     
cqlsh:rw> SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = 0;
code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Partition key part email must be restricted since preceding part is"
```

Now for your question -> yes it is possible because you have composite key partition key part only as userid.

Interesting source of info:
http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/refCompositePk.html

Good tool for tries is cqlsh - it helps you to test many things. For example in cqlsh output partition key columns are red, clustering columns cyan / blue and data columns violet - very helpful

**Update for comment**
Continuing second case, query

```
cqlsh:rw> SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = 0 AND email = '';

 userid | email | data
--------+-------+------
```

will succeed so as result you will have to specify always userid and email

To query one user and many email adresses you can use

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = 0 AND email IN ( 'a', '4' );

 userid | email | data
--------+-------+------
```

However IN clause is expensive since this mean that contact node will have to connect many nodes to gather data so better is to use parallel queries but you will have to specify email value as well. First select of second case ends with error. However from example one user can have many emails so first case should be sufficient - depends on expectation from db. In second case it will not work without email field.

In first case

```
CREATE TABLE users ( userid INT, email TEXT, data TEXT, PRIMARY KEY ( userid, email ) );
INSERT INTO users (userid, email , data ) VALUES( 0, 'email@a.pl', 'ddd');
INSERT INTO users (userid, email , data ) VALUES( 0, 'email1@a.pl', 'ddd1111');
```

you will insert some data clustered by email address and thus you will have relation one user -> many data by emails at least your question in comment suggest this. Here is result

```
cqlsh:rw> SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = 0;

 userid | email       | data
--------+-------------+---------
      0 | email1@a.pl | ddd1111
      0 |  email@a.pl |     ddd
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I have another question though. If i do it your way, i.e. have the `((userid, emailaddress))` as my partition key, will i still be able to search ONLY by the userid without specifying the emailaddress? With my example, i would be able to but i'm not sure i would be able to do it if both of them are partition keys.

Comment: @kha such case you have to use Allow Filtering